# Parameters in SAXParser 'startElement' method always null

Tags: java, xml, saxparser

I am trying to implement a sax parser to load some XML. However all the paramaters in the methods inside the DefaultHandler are always null. For example calling `System.out.println(uri);` inside the `startElement` method prints null. Code is below. No exceptions/errors are being printed anywhere when code is run. Any ideas/help are appreciated.

**Default Handler:**

```
    try {

        handler = new DefaultHandler(){
            int channel_amt = 0;

            public void startElement(String uri, String localname, String name, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

                if(name == "fixture"){
                    profileID++;
                    System.out.println(attributes.getValue(0));
                    profile_name = attributes.getValue(0);
                    profile_mode = attributes.getValue(1);
                    profile_channels.clear();
                } else {

                    if(name == "channel"){

                        profile_channel = new Vector<Object>();
                        profile_channel.addElement(attributes.getValue(0));
                        profile_channel.addElement(attributes.getValue(1));
            //          profile_channel.addElement(Boolean.parseBoolean(attributes.getValue(2)));

                        channel_amt++;
                        if(Arrays.asList(channels).indexOf(attributes.getValue(1)) != -1){
                            profile_channel_function[Arrays.asList(channels).indexOf(attributes.getValue(1))] = channel_amt;
                        }

                    } else {
                        profile_channel.addElement(new Range(Integer.parseInt(attributes.getValue(0)), Integer.parseInt(attributes.getValue(1)), attributes.getValue(2)));
                    }

                } 

            }       
            public void endElement(String uri, String localname, String name) throws SAXException {

                if(name == "fixture"){
                    profile[profileID] = new Profile(profile_name, profile_mode, profile_channels, profile_built_in_dimmer, profile_channel_function);
                } else if(name == "channel"){
                    profile_channels.add(profile_channel);
                }

            }
        };

        loadProfile("Dimmer.xml");

    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**loadProfile Method:**

```
    public void loadProfile(String name){
        for(int c=0;c<51;c++){
            profile_channel_function[c] = 0;
        }

        SAXParser parser;
        try {
            parser = factory.newSAXParser();
            parser.parse(new File(name), handler);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Thankyou in advance.

Comment: Don't use `==` to compare strings. Use the `equals()` method.

Comment: @jsheeran that led me to the solution! thankyou